# data doesn't update on all bindings

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I have two Windows, my MainWindow and a CounterWindow; on the MainWindow is a button with a binding and on my CounterWindow is a label with the same binding

When data is retrieved, the Button does receive the new data, but the CounterWindow label doesn't update.

Note, it turns to 0 on initializing (so the Binding functions!(?))

```
    public class CounterModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public string CurrentCount {
            get { return mCurrentCount; }
            set
            {
                if (value == mCurrentCount) return;
                mCurrentCount = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }

        }

        public CounterModel() {
            UpdateCounters();
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName]string propertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }

        string mCurrentCount;

        public void UpdateCounters(int i = 0)
        {
            CurrentCount = i.ToString();
        }

    }
}
```

MainWindow codehbehind:

```
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            CounterBtn.DataContext = cntMdl;
        }

        CounterModel cntMdl = new CounterModel();
```

CounterWindow CodeBehind:

```
        public CounterWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = new CounterModel();
        }
```

CounterWindow Xaml

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding CurrentCount}" FontSize="900" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontFamily="Consolas" Foreground="White" MouseDown="TextBlock_MouseDown"/>
```

what am I missing?

Comment: `CounterBtn.DataContext = cntMdl;` is called before `CounterModel cntMdl = new CounterModel();` so it will be `null`. Besides that, you should not create a new CounterModel at all. Use the one and only instance for both windows.

Comment: It is also strange that you assign the DataContext of a single control like CounterBtn. You would usually assign it at the window level, and the controls in the window will inherit it.

Comment: I only want that button to have that specific datacontext, the rest of the window will have a different context 

I was unable to call UpdateCounters() without using cntMdl.. I am afraid that there is something i'm doing wrong somewhere, but I cannot see where

Comment: p.s., the reason why it was working is because I stripped some code; the ```CounterModel cntMdl = new CounterModel();``` is a variable declared outside of any void; the ```CounterBtn.DataContext = cntMdl;``` is declared in ```public MainWindow()``` Sorry for the confusion there -- Updated the Codesamples

Comment: Hmm.. Is it because I use ```new CounterModel();``` ?... how do I reuse the one that already exists?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not create a new CounterModel instance for the CounterWindow. Remove

```
DataContext = new CounterModel();
```

from the CounterWindow constructor.

In case you are showing the CounterWindow from the Button's Click event handler, pass the current DataContext to the new window:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var button = (Button)sender;
    var window = new CounterWindow { DataContext = button.DataContext };
    window.Show();
}
```

Comment: `CounterModel cntMdl = new CounterModel();`

`CounterWindow CounterWindow = new CounterWindow { DataContext = cntMdl };`
Does throw 
`A field initializer cannot reference the nonstatic field, method, or property`